# Scoped bean: inject one into another

Tags: java, spring, scope

How to inject a session scoped bean into another session scoped bean without proxy?

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
class Foo {
    @Inject Bar bar;
}

@Component
@Scope("session")
class Bar {
}
```

It reports error "No matching bean". Though  a `TARGET_CLASS` scope-proxy could resolve this problem, but why do I need a proxy for same scoped beans?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you use `@Autowired` instead of `@Inject`?

Comment: You need to include more information, wiring session-scoped beans between beans of the same scope works fine without proxies. I assume in your code @Component is spelled correctly? Is your Bar class picked up by the component scan?

Comment: @mrembisz: Yes, it's @Component, my mistake. `to include more information` - how?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is - because at the injection point spring doesn't distinguish injected beans depending on the scope of the current bean. It needs a proxy to fetch the target bean (from the session in this case), disregarding the scope of the bean where it's injected into.

Comment: In the Scope interface, there is a conversationId, if two session beans belong to the same session, their conversationId should be the same, and then the proxy is not necessary, isn't it? A scope proxy relies on calling `Scope.get("beanName")` on the fly to get the bean belong to the current context could also break the dependencies.

Comment: Well, it could be. Spring can apply it after it has resolved the proxy. I don't know exactly, but it somehow makes sense not to take into account the scope of the bean that gets dependencies injected.

Comment: Take an example: If you have foo:1(bar:proxy->bar:1) for session:1 serialized, and later restored in session:2, now, bar:proxy will point to bar:2, then foo:1 is broken.

Comment: After scanned the spring source code, I didn't see any usage of `Scope.getConversationId`, it seems just a reserved method.