# SpringMVC session scoped objects not being persisted between subsequent calls to controller

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc

I have a controller

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class CartManagementController
{
   @Autowired
   private ShoppingCart cart;

   @RequestMapping("/addToCart")
   public ModelAndView addToCart(@RequestParam("id") int id)
   {
      // now just use the cart
   }  
}
```

And a session scoped bean:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class ShoppingCart
{
   // just a plain java class - member variables and methods as usual
}
```

I am getting an intermittent problem where the session is not persisted between subsequent requests to addToCart(). On the first call the cart is available and something is added. On the next request a new cart object is being created. As a result only after two calls to addToCart only one item is in the cart. After the second call the session is persisted as expected. It is only the first call that is not persisted.

Comment: Interesting if `@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` changes anything - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991114/scoped-bean-inject-one-into-another. P.S. I believe, Controller should be a singleton and not a request scoped bean.

Comment: `@Scope("request")` on controller seems strange to me

Comment: If the controller is a singleton then there will be race condition as multiple threads try to access Session scoped cart beans.

Comment: A. Session scope is wider than the request scope, so request scope for the controller won't help - the cart should be thread safe. B. in the request scoped proxy mode different threads will work with the respective  cart instances via proxy.

Comment: @user2009039 If the ShoppingCart is not thread-safe and you have multiple concurrent requests **using the same session** then it doesn't matter what scope you have for you Controller, you will still have potential race-conditions. Scope has no impact on threading in the web container, only on object creation and life-cycle. madhead is right, you should not scope your Controller and Boris is right, you need to set the `proxyMode` parameter.

Comment: I did a little further debugging and it appears that new cart instances are sometimes created for the same session. More specifically the cart created during the first request of the session is lost. Only on the second request is the cart persisted in the session.  The error is not related to a race condition within the cart object.